# Prevent Multiple Submission in Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a google form with member id inside. Can I prevent the same member id to submit the same form twice by using Google Apps Script maybe?

Comment: There is a setting in google form which allows user to fill form once only. The setting that needs to be enabled is "Limit to 1 response"

Comment: @shabnambharmal But this setting will require user to login using their google account right?

Comment: You can delete previous responses with the same member id.

Comment: How do you put the member id inside the Google Form?  Prefilled link?  You'd need to have a separate Form file for every member, then delete the Google Form file after they submitted it once.

Comment: @SandyGood the member id can be just a text box for them to fill in. I am not sure this can be done or not? What I actually want is when user key in member id and fill in everything in the form, when they click submit button, it will check all the previous response whether the keyed in member id exist or not

Comment: It's possible to search existing data for the same value that a user entered into the Form, and then if the same value is found, then delete the current data.  But you can't stop the user from submitting the Form from a test made on their computer.  A Google Form can't use client-side JavaScript.  You can only stop the user from getting the Form a second time.  And if the user is not logged into a Google account, then there is no built-in way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

There are no pre-submission validation opportunities. The only option is to "remove" duplicate "memberID" entries in the Form Response Spreadsheet.

This formula (placed in cell A1 of a blank sheet in the Form Response spreadsheet) will do that.

`=ArrayFormula(sort(vlookup(query({row('Form Responses 1'!A:A),sort('Form Responses 1'!A:D)},"select max(Col1) group by Col3 label max(Col1)''",0),{row('Form Responses 1'!A:A),sort('Form Responses 1'!A:D)},{2,3,4,5},0),1,0))`

In my scenario, form responses are received in sheet = `Form Responses 1`. I created a second sheet = `uniquesubmissions` to put the array formula that would query the responses. I also formatted Column A of the `uniquesubmissions` sheet as Date/Time.

---

**Note** there ten Submissions, but only eight Unique Submissions. Member ID 'S73895' made 3 submissions, but we are only recognising the most recent of those, and ignoring the others. An option would be to reverse the sort order and only accept the oldest.

[image: Form Responses]

---

[image: Unique Form Responses]

---

**Explanation (paraphrasing the original source)**
`{row('Form Responses 1'!A:A),sort('Form Responses 1'!A:D)}`

- Creates a new (virtual array), consisting of 5 columns: 1 column with the row numbers + 4 columns of the original table (but sorted, so that the 'latest' dates will be at the bottom of the table)

`query({row('Form Responses 1'!A:A),sort('Form Responses 1'!A:D)},"select max(Col1) group by Col3 label max(Col1)''",0)`

The query selects the max row number (col1) (per name (group by Col3)).

- These row numbers (returned by the query) are 'looked' up in the same 'virtual' array (see above) and on match, columns 2, 3, 4 and 5 are returned.

---

**Credit**
This formula was adapted from a design by  [JPV](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/83521/jpv) in an answer in Webapps, [Google Spreadsheet Query for unique and “most recent”](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/75312/google-spreadsheet-query-for-unique-and-most-recent)